# SQL Like crashing on "/"

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a column with datatype varchar using MySQL database. Suppose the value from a web form that gets saved in this column is : `2/4/2013`

My search query goes like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE colValue LIKE %2/4/2013%
```

But, it is crashing. For any other string am getting correct results. But, is it the forward slash which makes it crash. How can this be fixed ?

Regards !

Comment: JW's answer below is the fix, the reason it's crashing is that `LIKE` needs a `'` quoted string, `'%2/4/2013%'`. Problem is, you'll also hit `22/4/2013` with that LIKE, since `%` matches anything.

Comment: In SQL, as in other languages, string literals are enclosed between single quotes. Other than that, using string functions to manipulate dates is not necessarily a good option.

Answer (score 4):

since you want to select for specific date, why not use `=`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE colValue = '2/4/2013'
```

but if the data type of the column is `DATE` or `DATETIME`, use proper formatting although mysql automatically converts it,

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE colValue = '2013-02-04'
```

Answer (score 1):

For Using like operator you could use DATEPART() function...

```
select * from tbl
where (DATEPART(yy, colValue) = 2013
AND DATEPART(mm, colValue) = 04
AND DATEPART(dd, colValue) = 02)
```

Like this you can do like in SQL

Comment: MySQL does not have a `DATEPART()` function as far as I know. Where you thinking of SQL Server maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use an escape character for the /. The mysql escape character is the \.

Comment: 1) Forward slash does not need escaping: it doesn't have any special meaning in MySQL 2) You cannot have unquoted string literals, no matter what you escape.